# Keep Edge sidebar webapps loaded

Tags: browser, microsoft-edge

I was excited to find capability of Microsoft Edge sidebar. I was quick to ping my mail, whatsapp, note taking app and calendar app to it. But I found that when I collapse the pinned website in the sidebar and re-open it at some time in future, the website simply reloads. The delay is even more for whatsapp as whatsapp desktop site takes too long to load in browser. This simply defeats the very purpose of sidebar: multi tasking.

Is there any way to keep websites pinned to sidebar always loaded? Am I missing some basic info?

PS: I mean [this](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2022/09/01/microsoft-edge-sidebar-multitask-smarter/) by edge sidebar.

OS: Windows 10
Browser: Microsoft Edge Version 110.0.1587.50 (Official build) (64-bit)

**Update**

It seems that sidebar webapp instances / sessions are not shared across browser windows!! If I open whatsapp from sidebar in browser window-1, then collapse it and next time if I open whatsapp from sidebar in browser window-2, it will log out whatsapp from sidebar of window-1 and relogin in window-2 sidebar !!

Comment: Please add more details like name an version of the operative system an web browsers that you are using, explain why [tag:google-chrome] and [tag:microsoft-edge] are included (it's not clear if the case described refers to windows from the same web browser or if they are from different web browsers), search throughly, show your understanding regarding how web broswers work, show what you found and why it didn't meet your needs.

Comment: P.S. Nowadays Microsoft browsers support multiple operating systems. Ref. [Microsoft Edge supported Operating Systems](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-supported-operating-systems).

Comment: I removed google-chrome tag. Earlier I added it so that more people will notice the question and since people who dabble in both browsers may be aware of this. This feature is only available in Microsoft Edge and not Google chrome. So, both windows  are of Edge browser. Added my OS and Edge browser version. I hope things are clear now.